# What is the equivalent of glDrawPixels() in OpenGL ES 1.1?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Can anyone tell me the equivalent of [`glDrawPixels()`](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=man&fname=/usr/share/catman/g_man/cat3/OpenGL/gldrawpixels.z) in OpenGL ES 1.1?

Answer (score 4):

You're forced to use a texture.

Comment: a texture, and `GL_OES_draw_texture`. glDrawTexOES shortcuts the need to pass triangles and such. http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_draw_texture.txt

Comment: How would you do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Put your pixel coordinates in a vertex array and draw it with GL_POINTS.

See http://gorillas.lyndir.com/trac/browser/Classes/SkyLayer.m ([Gorillas](http://gorillas.lyndir.com) code)

[edit]
This solution is only useful if you're drawing dots on the screen.  When I posted it, I had no clue what glDrawPixels() was and assumed drawing dots was the question.

Do not use this for drawing arbitrary pixel data ...

Comment: This sounds like a horrible solution. Using a texture must be better in almost all ways.

Comment: unwind is right - this is a horrible solution, orders of magnitude less performant and err-prone than a texture.